# My computer loses network connectivity every 30 minutes

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, connection

My LAN connected PC loses network connectivity every 30 minutes. It has a static IP address and I've checked to make sure there aren't any IP conflicts on my network. If I'm streaming from that PC to my Xbox the stream will be interrupted and it normally takes about a minute to come back online. The same happens if I'm actually on the PC and just browsing the web.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to track down this issue. I've tried checking the available logs on my router to see if there is an issue with DCHP but have been unsuccessful in finding any evidence. Any suggestions would be helpful. I can't think of any recent changes to my network, PC or software installations that may have caused this.
I am a software developer and have intermediate networking knowledge.

EDIT: During the last outage my PC was not able to connect to the router. A separate laptop was connected to wireless at the time and had no issues browsing the internet or connecting to the router. A new symptom however has arisen. The Xbox 360, connected via ethernet cable, was not able to connect to Xbox Live. This is the first time this has happened. No devices connected via wireless (laptop, iPhone, iPad) had any connectivity issues, but two ethernet connected devices had issues.

EDIT: During one outage I told windows to troubleshoot the network problem and it said that it could automatically fix the problem by changing DCHP info. It basically said my network adapter from static to automatically obtain. This did fix the issue quicker than just waiting it out, but the outage occurred again 30 minutes later even when leaving those settings.

Comment: Have you confirmed that only that one computer loses connectivity?  How is it connected to your network?  Are there any other computers connected in the same way?  When did the problem start?  Is the Static IP set in the router, or at the PC?

Comment: Can you reach the router during the interruptions in connectivity? If not, is your network wired or wireless? If so, what kind of Internet connection do you have? (Cable? DSL? Satellite?)

Comment: Only that computer loses connectivity. It is hard wired. The static IP address is set via that ethernet adapter on the PC. Other computers are hard wired to the router, some with static IP addresses. Problem started a couple weeks ago. I am not sure whether or not I can reach the router. I will test that. The connection is Comcast Cable.

Comment: Does your network have a wireless segment which might be letting someone in (temporarily) on a DHCP lease that is an IP collision with your computer?  This isn't a probability, I'm just brainstorming.

Comment: Hmmmm, I don't think that would be the issue. Can someone provide me some information on how DHCP leasing works? I've read up that since this occurs every half hour it most likely has something to do with the router sending a DHCP request to this PC. I'm just trying to understand it better so I might be able to track this down. Is there  some sort of logging utility that I could run on the PC that might give me information on what is happening when the outage occurs.

Comment: @LoganGarland: Windows as a built in logger that will probably tell what the problem is, check [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Using-Windows-Network-Diagnostics-event-logs-to-solve-network-problems) how to use it.